# Get sharepoint list name Dynamically

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, caml-query, view

I have some page with multiple views. I want to write a custom filter for default active view.

How can I get **list or view properties** such as **(View or list )name** using SharePoint CSOM (or other approaches)when Added **Web part** to the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the Xsltlistview web part to the page using JSOM/CSOM, and then define the view and make the changes to it (such as set query for the view).

Demo: [Add an XsltListViewWebPart With a Custom View Using JSOM](http://blog.bonzai-intranet.com/analysthq/2014/10/adding-an-xsltlistviewwebpart-with-a-custom-view-using-javascript/).